# How to export oracle 11g user to 10g and on a different default tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tablespace, impdp

I have an 11g database and I want to export a dump to import it later on a 10g database. I can use expdp with option VERSION=10.2 but my problem is that I have to import this dump on a different tablespace.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`REMAP_TABLESPACE` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL929) during the import:

> Remaps all objects selected for import with persistent data in the source tablespace to be created in the target tablespace.

You can specify multiple mappings if necessary.