# How can I use imp command with REMAP_TABLESPACE?

Tags: oracle

With Oracle 11g, how can I use imp command to import schema from a different database that was already exported to  a dmp file and which its tablespace needs to be renamed during the import?

I understand that there's a REMAP_TABLESPACE command but I only found how to use it with impdp and I need System DBA privileges for that, and I don;t have it.

Thanks

Comment: `imp` does not support that paramter. It's one of the (many) limitations of the (deprecated) `imp` command. There is no workaround.

Comment: Why `imp`? Use `impdp`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28499284/3989608

Comment: I would use impdp but i need specific privileges for creating directory and i don't have it

Comment: If the export was done using `expdp` you can't use `imp` anyway. So you will need to ask your DBA to give you access to a directory and copy the dump file to the Oracle server.

Comment: You could just ask for access to the default directory `DATA_PUMP_DIR`

Comment: due to business issue it will take some time till we get the permissions and the export was performed by the exp command. Same goes for the data_Pump_dir no one can give us the permission right now, so i need to find a way to do this with imp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We closed this issue with one of our DBAs to refresh the schema with the relevant data, but yes it seems that impdp/expdp was the best way if we had the permissions.
Thanks for all the help.